# gmapping: "Skipping XML Document..."

Tags: ros, pointcloud-to-laserscan, xml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Firing up an instance of pointcloud_to_laserscan_node (not the nodelet) on Indigo + Ubuntu gets

```
[ERROR] [1509665358.223587616]: Skipping XML Document "/opt/ros/indigo/share/gmapping/nodelet_plugins.xml" which had no Root Element.  This likely means the XML is malformed or missing.
```

Two questions:

1. Why would pointcloud_to_laserscan be looking for a file in slam_gmapping?
2. Can we safely ignore this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274849/gmapping:-%22skipping-xml-document...%22/) by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 567 on 2017-11-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-03**:
May I suggest a topic title change? The error message specifically states that `/opt/ros/../gmapping/nodelet_plugins.xml` has a problem. `pointcloud_to_laserscan` is not mentioned anywhere.

**Comment by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) on 2017-11-28**:
Just saw this comment. Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

update: PR#56 was merged, new version of `gmapping` is in the [shadow repository](http://wiki.ros.org/ShadowRepository) and should be available in the regular repositories after the next sync.

---

This is probably [ros-perception/slam_gmapping#55](https://github.com/ros-perception/slam_gmapping/issues/55).

Can you verify there is a `nodelet_plugins.xml` in the `/opt/ros/indigo/share/gmapping` directory?

If not, that is the cause. The `CMakeLists.txt` is not `install(..)`ing that file (at least in the [current version](https://github.com/ros-perception/slam_gmapping/blob/eba9c1b384a04cbb2171ed4c52c4841e806d7a08/gmapping/CMakeLists.txt)), which makes things work in a `devel` space, but not in an `install` space. As the binary pkgs contain only `install(..)`ed artefacts, `nodelet_plugins.xml` is missing from those.

This seems to have been introduced in [ros-perception/slam_gmapping#41](https://github.com/ros-perception/slam_gmapping/pull/41), which added the nodelet version of `gmapping`.

> Why would pointcloud_to_laserscan be looking for a file in slam_gmapping?

it isn't. It looks that way, but in reality the `rospkg` plugin infrastructure is just iterating over all ROS pkgs it knows and trying to load the `nodelet_plugins.xml` file that `gmapping` has listed in its package manifest.

You just happen to be starting `pointcloud_to_laserscan`.

> Can we safely ignore this?

Yes. If you're not intending to use the nodelet version of `gmapping`, you should be fine.

---

Edit: I've submitted a PR to fix this: [ros-perception/slam_gmapping#56](https://github.com/ros-perception/slam_gmapping/pull/56). Note that `gmapping` will have to go through a full release cycle before the binaries on the repositories contain this fix.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1